# Given the previous conditons, find the probability that Gabriel will wash the second day given that nobody washed the first day.

Tags: probability

> Gabriel and Dan just started using a random device to decide who washes the dishes. They toss a fair coin four times. Gabriel washes with 3 heads or more, and Dan washes with 3 tails or more; otherwise they leave it until tomorrow. The next day they repeat the procedure, but if no one is assigned in two days, Gabriel gives up and washes them in that day.
>
> a) Find the probability that Gabriel will wash the second day given that nobody washed the first day.
>
> b) Probability that no one washed the first day given that Gabriel washed the second day.

For (a) I got P(G2) = 5/14 and P(N1) = 4/14. But I am getting P(G2|N1) = 0.357

Is this right?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: a) What is the probability of two or more heads? b) Let $G$ be the event Gabriel washed the second day, and $N$ the event no one washed the first day.  We want $\Pr(N\mid G)$, which is $\Pr(N\cap G)/\Pr(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

> a) Find the probability that Gabriel will wash the second day given that nobody washed the first day.

When given that, then Gabriel washes if Dan does not "win" the toss.   What is the probability that Dan does not "win" the toss.

> b) Probability that no one washed the first day given that Gabriel washed the second day.

Either: no-one washed the first day and Dan did not "win" the toss, or someone washed the first day and Gabriel "won" the toss.   What is the probability of the former given that one of either happened?